# How to use a custom folder icon when using jstree to create a node?

Tags: jquery, jstree

No problem creating a default custom folder using jstree, for example,

```
 $("#treeFile1").jstree({ 
 "plugins" : ["themes","html_data","ui","crrm","types"], 
    "types" : {
        "valid_children" : [ "none" ],
    "types" : {
            "rootNote" : {
                    "valid_children" : ["none"],
           "icon" : { "image" : "/bk/tree/_demo/customFolder.png"}
},
  } 
  });
```

The comes when attempting to create node with the custom folder after the above code has started.

here is my failed attempt:

```
$("#treeFile1").jstree("create", null, "outside", {"attr" : {"rel" : "rootNote"}});
```

Note: no error messages shown from Firefox console

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why but after removing valid_children property and its value, it resolved this problem.

```
$("#treeFile1").jstree({ 
                          "plugins" : ["themes","html_data","ui","crrm","types"], 
                          "types" : {
                                       "types" : {
                                                   "rootNote" : {

                         "icon" : { "image" : "/bk/tree/_demo/customFolder.png"}
                                            },
                                   } 
                          });
```